# Why isn't `validates_uniqueness_of` failing validation when creating a record with duplicate values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails version 3.2.13.

Here's my model definition:

```
module Recipes
  class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ApplicationHelper

    attr_accessible :body, :title, :author, :photos, :tags

    has_many :photos
    has_many :favorites
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :tags, :through => :taggings

    belongs_to :author,
               :class_name => :User,
               :foreign_key => :author_id

    before_create :default_values
    before_save :create_slug

    validates_presence_of :title, :body, :author
    validates_uniqueness_of :title, :slug

    def create_slug
      self.slug = ApplicationHelper.slugify(self.title)
    end

    def default_values
      self.view_count ||= 0
    end
  end
end
```

If I create a record with the title 'Test Title #1', and try to create another one with the title 'Test Title #1', I get a validation error stating the title has already been taken. If I create a record with the title 'Test Title #1', and try to create another one with the title 'Test Title 1', it succeeds. The generated slugs for both records are the same, 'test-title-1', which should not happen.

This is the code for `slugify`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def self.slugify(text)
    text.gsub(/[\W]+/, " ").strip.gsub(/[\s]+/, "-").downcase
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of operations (at least the relevant ones for your model) looks like this:

1. `before_validation` callbacks.
2. Validations.
3. `before_save` callbacks.
4. Save to database.

You can find a complete list in the [Active Record Callbacks Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks).

So your `create_slug` method (a `before_save` callback) is called *after* the validations have been performed. If you want to ensure that your slugs are unique you should:

```
before_validation :create_slug
```

so that the slug will be set up *before* the validations execute.